# Using CMake to build project but then adding more libraries to VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, opengl, cmake

I would like to build a program with Visual Studio which will depend on 4 different libraries(OpenCV,OpenGL,ALVAR,...).

I checked that one of these libraries needs to be built using CMake.After building the project correctly, I now want to add through the visual studio, the other libraries through project properties->additional dependencies etc.

However when I compile my program, it seems that I have reloaded something which has a conflict with CMake and I get a new VS programme without all the stuff I added(libraries).

What is the best way to build the program? Use a correct CMAKE file which will include all libraries together? Or just use VS? Isn't there any way to build with CMAKE one of the libraries-->get solution-->add more libraries dependencies-->compile correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to use CMake to generate your program, and the libraries.

If you use `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARY(your_program lib1 lib2 openCV openGL...)`, then in Visual Studio, your program will have dependencies on each libs.

Comment: Yes but right now I have 4 different libraries.3 of them have include folder+dlls/libs, while the 4th one has src code and cmakelists file which calls 1 of the other 3 libraries.What should I do?Build a brand new cmakelists file and start a new project combining all 4?Any good tutorials on how to combine several libraries(built or not built) together?

Comment: You can have a cmake for the lib you build, ie with sources, and you just add the already compiled libs to the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARY, they will be added to the linker phase.